# python-xarray: How to create a Dataset and assign results of an iteration to the Dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have a for loop which is running some analysis on some data and returning some values. For boring reasons, this loop cannot easily be vectorised. I want to create a Dataset and then assign the result of the for loop to the Dataset as I iterate through.

## `Dataset.update`

If I write some code which uses [`Dataset.update`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.update.html) as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from xarray import Dataset, cftime_range, concat

times = cftime_range(start="2024-01-01", end="2024-01-02", freq="H")

test_xarray = Dataset(coords={"time": None, "mlt": np.arange(24)})

for time in times:
    test_for_this_time = Dataset({"x": (["time", "mlt"], np.random.random((1, 24)))},
                                 coords={"time": np.array([time]), "mlt": np.arange(24)})
    test_xarray.update(test_for_this_time)

print(test_xarray)
```

I get the following:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 1, mlt: 24)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) object 2024-01-01 00:00:00
  * mlt      (mlt) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
Data variables:
    x        (time, mlt) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan nan
```

## `Dataset.merge`

This is clearly not what I want, and so I tried using [`Dataset.merge`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.merge.html) instead of `update`.

```
import numpy as np
from xarray import Dataset, cftime_range, concat

times = cftime_range(start="2024-01-01", end="2024-01-02", freq="H")

test_xarray = Dataset(coords={"time": None, "mlt": np.arange(24)})

for time in times:
    test_for_this_time = Dataset({"x": (["time", "mlt"], np.random.random((1, 24)))},
                                 coords={"time": np.array([time]), "mlt": np.arange(24)})
    test_xarray = test_xarray.merge(test_for_this_time)

print(test_xarray)
```

I get the following:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 25, mlt: 24)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) object 2024-01-01 00:00:00 ... 2024-01-02 00:00:00
  * mlt      (mlt) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
Data variables:
    x        (time, mlt) float64 0.6399 0.6227 0.7972 ... 0.7804 0.8763 0.7198
```

This does do what I want, so hurrah, but I don't understand what I did wrong in the first method, which I would have expected to work.

## Is this the best method?

I'm curious as to whether I'm using xarray in the best way here. I've looked through Stack Overflow and through the documentation and I can't see any examples of this sort of workflow. I've also tried with [`xarray.concat`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.concat.html), but that doesn't quite seem to do what I want; it leaves the first `None` value in the `time` dimension. It might be that the method above is the best way, but if not, I would greatly appreciate any advice on how better to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the proposed methods with `Dataset.update` and `Dataset.merge` are not ideal.
It shouldn't be necessary to create a new Dataset in every iteration of the for-loop, with the sole purpose of adding new data to an existing Dataset.

In your example, the coordinates over which you iterate are known before the for-loop.
Therefore, my suggestion is to create first a `Dataset` containing a `DataArray` of the correct shape but unfilled (or filled with dummy values), and then fill the values in the for-loop:

```
import numpy as np
from xarray import Dataset, cftime_range, concat

times = cftime_range(start="2024-01-01", end="2024-01-02", freq="H")
mlt = np.arange(24)

test_xarray = Dataset(
    {"x": (["time", "mlt"], np.empty((times.size, mlt.size)))},
    coords={"time": times, "mlt": mlt},
)

for i, time in enumerate(times):
    test_xarray.x[i] = np.random.random(mlt.size)
```

Would this be feasible for your application?